# Views: nodes grouped by taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views, css-js-aggregation

I would like to show nodes grouped (aggregated?) by taxonomy term like this:

term 1

- node1
- node43
- node34

term 2

- node23

etc. but I am not seeing such grouping when I enable aggregation. I can get sg similar with table style and group by column but this only works for the current page, not if I have a paged view.

Any tips? What would be the steps to achieve this with aggregation?

Similar question but for D6

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712856/how-do-i-make-a-view-that-groups-nodes-by-taxonomy-term
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/print-nodes-grouped-by-taxonomy-term-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree) module which provides a view style plugin for that. It couples two views by means of an argument, one view would be your term listing, the other - node listing. I have tried to achieve that by aggregation or grouping field, but to no avail - Views is apparently designed so that it can list only one kind of a bundle at a time.

Although, if you don't need to represent entire tree, you could try trying out field style, with taxonomy term field added, and then used as grouping field.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I think this recipe is pretty awsome: http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/taxonomy/views

Answer (score 0):

if you choose **Force using fields** under *display settings*, you are able to add fields and then group by them, still using rendered entity as display !