# Loop Custom Content based on the taxonomy term they are in

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I created a taxonmy vocabulary, added 3 terms in it 
Term1, Term2, Term3

Then I created a custom content type, and I associated it with that vocabulary term, so now everytime I create a page I check to which Term they belong to,

What I want to do is 
Loop the name of the Term + all the pages titles and body that belong to that term

For example:

```
<h1>Term1</h1>
<ul>
 <li>Page 1 title </li>
 <li>Page 2 title </li>
 </ul>
<h1>Term2</h1>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Views: nodes grouped by taxonomy term](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29711/views-nodes-grouped-by-taxonomy-term)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer I was looking for

```
<?php
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'analize'));
$listAnalize = [];
foreach ( $nodes as $kNod => $vNod ) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load( $vNod->field_categoria_analizei['und'][0]['tid'] );

  $listAnalize[$vNod->field_categoria_analizei['und'][0]['tid']]['denumire'] = $term->name;
  $listAnalize[$vNod->field_categoria_analizei['und'][0]['tid']]['analize'][] = $vNod;
}
?>
```